# where should the remote-server element located when configurating clickhouse cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, clickhouse

I'm setting up a clickhouse cluster, as the tutorial said the "remote_servers" should be added, then I turn to /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml, I see <remote_servers incl="clickhouse_remote_servers"> followed with
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHBBg.png . 
  I'm confused with these files , /etc/metrika.xml and /yandex/name_of_substitution. who can give a example, thanks

Answer (score 5):

It could be specified in two ways.

1. In separate file (/etc/metrika.xml by default).
   Create this file, make it accessible for read (chown 644 is enough).
   And write inside something like this:

   ```
   <yandex>
       <clickhouse_remote_servers>       <!-- name of substitution-->
           <logs_all>                    <!-- name of cluster (arbitary) to be specified in parameter of Distributed table -->
               <shard>
                   <replica>
                       <host>example01-01-1t.yandex.ru</host>
                       <port>9000</port>
                   </replica>
                   <replica>
                       <host>example01-01-2t.yandex.ru</host>
                       <port>9000</port>
                   </replica>
               </shard>
               <shard>
                   <replica>
                       <host>example02-01-1t.yandex.ru</host>
                       <port>9000</port>
                   </replica>
                   <replica>
                       <host>example02-01-2t.yandex.ru</host>
                       <port>9000</port>
                   </replica>
               </shard>
           </logs_all>
       </clickhouse_remote_servers>
   </yandex>
   ```
2. Directly inside config.xml file:

   ```
   <!-- Configuration of clusters that could be used in Distributed tables.
            https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#Distributed
     -->
   <remote_servers>
       <logs_all>                    <!-- name of cluster (arbitary) to be specified in parameter of Distributed table -->
           <shard>
               <replica>
                   <host>example01-01-1t.yandex.ru</host>
                   <port>9000</port>
               </replica>
               <replica>
                   <host>example01-01-2t.yandex.ru</host>
                   <port>9000</port>
               </replica>
           </shard>
           <shard>
               <replica>
                   <host>example02-01-1t.yandex.ru</host>
                   <port>9000</port>
               </replica>
               <replica>
                   <host>example02-01-2t.yandex.ru</host>
                   <port>9000</port>
               </replica>
           </shard>
       </logs_all>
   </remote_servers>
   ```

For convenience, server will create `/etc/clickhouse-server/preprocessed/config.xml` file at startup which contains all substitutions. It is just for review (not used by server).